# Make VoiceOver call out item position based on parent list

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

So I have the following type of list:

```
1. Item 1
  a. Sub-item a
  b. Sub-item b
2. Item 2
  c. Sub-item c
```

What I'm trying to do is make the sub-items a/b/c selectable using VoiceOver, where it would call out their positions based on which parent item they're in. i.e.:

```
> You're on Sub-item a, one out of two
> You're on Sub-item b, one out of two
> You're on Sub-item c, two out of two
```

Is that something that's possible using HTML Aria accessibility features? I've tried to find something online, but there's not too much documentation out there!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you dont need to do this really, you could just use nested ordered lists.

Answer (score 1):

If the items are a list of non-interactive items or simply text, then adding such descriptive contextual information is not necessary.

This is because the user chooses whether or not the item order should always be announced, typically under the screen reader's verbosity settings.

The user will be accustomed to how their screen reader announces ordered lists, and if their verbosity settings are already announcing the item order, then any additional text you add might be repetitive, potentially causing more confusion.

(If, instead, the items are interactive, you should consider marking it up as a [tree view](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/treeview/treeview-2/treeview-2a.html) or another interactive ARIA widget.)